# Is stack exchange available in Japanese?

Tags: discussion

I am unable to access in Japanese.

Comment: are you looking for http://ja.stackoverflow.com/ which is a Japanese stackoverflow, or are you looking for this site but operated in Japanese? This site japanese.stackexchange.com statistically functions in English, but it is perfectly fine to ask and answer questions in Japanese too. You may come across some questions/answers that have both English and Japanese versions.

Answer (score 4):

This site japanese.stackexchange.com statistically functions in English, but it is perfectly fine to ask and answer questions in Japanese too. You may come across some questions/answers that have both English and Japanese versions.

Some discussions on meta related to this:

- [Is an answer in Japanese only an answer suitable for this site?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/822/542)
- [Do questions have to be in English?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/542)

Answer (score 0):

Users can post in any language, but the site is essentially in English.
I believe StackExchange is owned by an American company, so the site is mostly in English.

It seems that they have 2 forums in foreign languages, one in Japanese and another in Russian, but both seem to be for computer programming:
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The first one is a Japanese language edition of Stack Overflow (note: not Stack Exchange), and is about programming. The second site is a Stack Exchange site about the Russian language, discussed in Russian.